# Understanding `regexp` in R

Tags: regex, string, r, foreach, iteration

Understanding regular expressions sometimes can be a trouble. Especially if your not really familiar writing them, like myself.

In **R** there are a couple of built-in functions (`base` package) which i would like to understand and be able to use. Like:

`grep` and `gsub`, that take as arguments `(p, x)` where `p` is a pattern and `x` is a character vector to look-up. `split` function also takes `regexp` as argument like many others.

Anyway i have an example such as:

```
string <- "39 22' 19'' N"
```

and i need to be able to extract numbers from it. So using these `stringr`, `iterators`, `foreach` libraries i am trying to figure out an expression using either `iter` or `foreach`.

`str_locate(string, "[0-9]+")` locates and `z <- str_extract(obj, "[0-9]+")` extracts only the first match on my string.

I have tried making something like

```
x <- iter(z)
nextElem(x)
```

but it doesn't work. And another one which normally doesn't work.

```
a <- foreach(iter(z))
a
```

How should i fix this using the above libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: @devnull yea your probably right

Comment: I think you need quotes in your definition of `string`

Comment: @Dason fixed thanks for observation

Answer (score 1):

Check http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf

```
str_extract_all(your_string, "[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have exactly the same result with the basic functions:

```
strsplit(gsub("(\\D+)"," ", string), " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it in base R:

```
string <- "39 22' 19'' N"
regmatches(string,gregexpr("[0-9]+",string))
# [[1]]
# [1] "39" "22" "19"
```

Note that `regmatches(...)` returns a list where each element is a char vector with the matches. So to get just the char vector you would use:

```
regmatches(string,gregexpr("[0-9]+",string))[[1]]
# [1] "39" "22" "19"
```